# Diagnosing a discrepancy in virtualenv behavior across similar Python installations

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I am comparing virtual envs across two legacy `Python 2.7.12` installations on two separate `Ubuntu 16.04` servers.

The first one is `Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS`, the second one is `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS`.

Both are running Django projects within virtual envs.

This question is about how the virtual envs are behaving *differently* across the two aforementioned installations. I need to understand and close this behavioral gap.

---

When I create a virtual env in the former installation, the output I see is:

```
created virtual environment CPython2.7.12.final.0-64 in 113ms
  creator CPython2Posix(dest=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, wheel=bundle, setuptools=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.1, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.36.1
  activators PythonActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,BashActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/get_env_details
```

When I create a virtual env in the latter installation, the output I see is:

```
New python executable in /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/get_env_details
```

Basically the first few lines of both outputs are different. Howcome?

---

Next, when I visit `~/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7` in the former installation, I see a few files:

[image]

However, I see many more files when I visit `~/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7` in the latter installation. Specifically:

[image]

---

**My questions are:**

1. Why are both virtual envs initializing differently when the underlying Python versions are the same?
2. I want to replicate the results of the latter installation in the former installation. How do I configure that?

---

I am asking this because there is a `celery+supervisor` installation that works perfectly on the latter environment, but fails in the former one. I need to diagnose and fix this failure.

In case it matters, that failure error is as follows:

```
    load_host_site()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 41, in load_host_site
    reload(sys.modules["site"])  # noqa # call system site.py to setup import libraries
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 164, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 19, in main
    load_host_site()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 52, in load_host_site
    add_site_dir = sys.modules["site"].addsitedir
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'addsitedir'
```

It seems that `.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site.py` in both installations is different. The error above is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is how `virtualenv` has been revamped after version `16.7.9`. The next version - `Version 20.0.0b1` - is a complete rewrite of the package.

The environments in the question are behaving differently because the former has `16.7.9`, whereas the latter is  `20.2.2`. Reverting to `16.7.9` has worked out.

Reference here https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/20.0.1/changelog.html#v20-0-0b1-2020-01-28